# Linux rm takes minutes on 100kB file

Tags: linux, filesystems, zfs

I'm encountering extremely slow deletion of files on a Linux machine with ZFS filesystem:

```
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root nfsnobody 297056 Jul 17  2018 somefile
$ time rm -f somefile
real    1m30.117s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.705s
```

Most cases take almost exactly 1.5 minutes. This does not happen with every file: At the time I'm trying to delete files that are withing an installation of Python and these files have been there for a while (days to months). Also, if I create a file in the same location and then try to delete it (seconds to minutes later), the problem does not occur and takes milliseconds.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt count=1024 bs=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.0191559 s, 54.7 MB/s

$ time rm -f file.txt
real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Any ideas on how to start debugging this? Are there any logs that would contain a record of filesystem operations? Is there a way to enable some logging to get lower level information during a specific `rm` operation?

The machine seems to be operating normally with low cpu and ram usage, no swapping and the disks have plenty of space left. This is the kernel in the machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux servername 3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 18 19:05:49 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Additional information about the file system:

```
$ df .
Filesystem       1K-blocks        Used   Available Use% Mounted on
mypool/wrk     67737890560 51963463040 15774427520  77% /wrk

$ zpool list
NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
mypool    98T  75.7T  22.3T         -    28%    77%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Comment: The `nfsnobody` vaguely suggests that you might not be on a local disk at all. Does `df .` identify this as a local ZFS partition?

Comment: @triplee, I edited the question adding details to answer your question. It is a local disk. There is an NFS server serving this mount, with about 20-30 clients, though, and I suspect that is the origin of the group name.

Comment: You could see if you are getting IO errors in `/var/log/syslog`.